# How to resume it when i click resume button?

Tags: android, handler, runnable, thread-sleep, postdelayed

//Counter of time since app started ,a background task

```
    private long mStartTime = 0L;
```

//Private long mPauseTime = 0L;

```
    private TextView mTimerLabel;
```

//Handler to handle the message to the timer task

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;

    String timerStop1;



     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     mTimerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);


     if(mStartTime == 0L){
         mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
         mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);

       }                

        timerPauseButton.setTag(1);
        timerPauseButton.setText("Pause");



 final Button timerPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimerPause);

        timerPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
```

//ChangeButtonText

```
                  final int status =(Integer) view.getTag();

                  if(status == 1) {
                      mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

                      mTimerLabel.setText(timerStop1);

                      timerPauseButton.setText("Resume");
                      view.setTag(0); //resume
                  } else{

                      mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                      mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
                      timerPauseButton.setText("Pause");
                      view.setTag(1); //pause
                      }

            }
        });

   }
```

//End of OnCreate

```
   private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable(){

            public void run() { 
                 {
                  final long start = mStartTime;
                  long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- start;

                  int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                  int minutes = seconds / 60;
                  seconds = seconds % 60;

                  mTimerLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                                                  + String.format("%02d", seconds));                             

                  timerStop1 = minutes + ":"
                                + String.format("%02d", seconds);

                  mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);         
                  }

            }    
    };
```

Why I click the pause button but timer also will run in background? Example when I click pause in 3sec after 5sec I click resume but it continue go on with 8sec and not 3sec?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` clock keeps running when the device is not in deep sleep. You only capture the start clock time once in `mStartTime`, so the difference between current `upTimeMillis()` and `mStartTime` grows. Pausing only stops the `mUpdateTimeTask` that formats the time difference to `mTimerLabel`.

Comment: So... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I use one button to do the pause and resume timer function. The pause function i done already but the resume function have some bugs... so anyone teach me with coding?

Comment: laalto: do you understand? cos I survey can use thread.sleep but dont know how to use it or you know any better way to fix this?